# hit/meet a deadline

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

I've just heard: *I have to make sure we hit the deadlines. There's a lot of emphasis on circulation figures this days...*

I know we say "meet a deadline" when something is finished by the date it was supposed to be finished, but I haven't found "hit" meaning this in any dictionary. Would you say "hit a deadline" is a common collocation and a synonym with "meet a deadline"?

For example: Can you say *If we can’t hit the deadline, they won’t give us another contract.*?

Comment: Usually it is " meet the deadline and hit the headlines".

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a common collocation. The preferred verb of the two, for taking *deadline* as object, is very clearly ([according to Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meet%20the%20deadline%2Chit%20the%20deadline&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3)) *meet.* Your interlocutor is probably confusing the journalistic imperative to *meet one’s deadlines* with the theatrical/cinematic imperative to *hit one’s marks.*

Answer (score 0):

The definitions behind the individual terms differ and it's easier, at a semantic level, to understand how 'meet' aligns with the sentiment of the phrase.
'Hit the deadline' is a more colloquial phrase and less formal. There is also the implied sentiment of enthusiasm or willingness to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

I found the expression in one of the coursebooks. It was in the chapter about journalism and I believe there might have been a mistake and the speaker just could have meant: "I have to make sure we hit the headlines" (just one letter - 'h' instead of 'd.' It makes sense in the context of journalism and the recording in which it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

A puritan would argue that *'to hit a deadline'* is grammatically wrong, illogical. To *hit* something means to *impact* on something, and you can't impact on a deadline, it can only be met or missed. Simon Heffer mentions this subject is his book *Strictly English:The Correct Way to Write and why it Matters* (which I can highly recommend).

I'm inclined to say that *'to hit a deadline'* is not grammatical.